# PHP/Vagrant - Host Accessing Host DB

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant

I setup vagrant with MySQL server and trying to get the PHP website to use the localhost DB and running into issues (Both, code and MySQL are on the same Vagrant VM). However, I have setup access via Sequel Pro and can access the DB with the same user and run queries. On the website, the queries aren't completed.

MySQL:

```
mysql> select db,host,user from mysql.db;
+-----+-----------+------+
| db  | host      | user |
+-----+-----------+------+
| ojs | localhost | ojs  |
| ojs | localhost | ojs2 |
| ojs | localhost | root |
+-----+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So 3 user is assigned to DB - to make life easier, I used `root` to make sure all permissions were `Y`.

In my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` I commented out `skip-internal-locking` and attempted to either comment out `bind-address` or set it to `0.0.0.0`

When I attempt to run a query from the browser (like validate a user). I look into `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`, the last query is:

```
160328 23:00:32   127 Connect   root@localhost on ojs
          127 Query SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`fname`, `User`.`lname`, `User`.`default_phone`, `User`.`default_ext`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`datecreated_ts`, `User`.`lastlogin_ts`, `User`.`last_deliveryaddress_id`, `User`.`last_billingaddress_id`, `User`.`auth_level`, `User`.`no_radio_email` FROM `User`   WHERE `User`.`email` = 'something@gmail.com' AND `User`.`password` = '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'
          127 Quit
```

So it looks like the query is running and I checked, that my `mysql` is making a connection.

I've been trying for two days and I'm beginning that i'm missing something fundamental. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is related to MySQL or Vagrant, it might come from your PHP code (have you tried to dump and die the return data from the query?)

Both your Web server and MySQL server at the same server so "bind-address" doesn't need to change. It won't affect.

You have a log of query sent to MySQL so there is no problem about the connection between your web and MySQL.

To detect the problem easier I think you should create a new PHP file to test your db, something like test_db.php, turn on the error reporting and display_errors. and see what happens

I notice your query is about selection for authentication, so you might have problem with authentication, check your session configuration, session start, session destroy, etc.

Hope it help you!

Comment: PHP will connect to Database if its outside the server (i.e. I can connect to our production DB fine). There are no errors in the error log on PHP and dumping queries keeps returning `false` as if its not finding the DB. I'll keep looking, however. Thanks.

Comment: Highly recommend you write and separate file uses PDO to test the connection, and check the log of mysql based on your query you pass on the test file.
Also check the upper and lower case of your query, if that is the problem modify your my.cnf at section [mysqld] add this line: lower_case_table_names=2, and also set the bind-address back to 0.0.0.0 to test
From sequel pro you can run the same query with the same user, so  granting privileges is fine.
And last check the way you initiated connection from PHP (dbname, host, port). Good luck! Guess I could not help you much.